# PHP Last variable in nested foreach loop not showing when echoed

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$criterias = $_POST['criteria'];
$criteriaValue = $_POST['criteriaValue'];
$comments = $_POST['Comments'];

foreach ($criteriaValue as $key => $value ){
  foreach( $criterias as $criteriaValue ){
    if( $criteriaValue == $key ){
      $string1 = $key;
      //echo $string1;
      foreach( $comments as $comment => $comm ){
        if( $string1 == $comment ){
          $string3 = $comm;
          //echo $string3;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  foreach ( $value as $result ){
    $string2 = $result;
    //echo $string2;
  }
  $criteria .= mysql_real_escape_string( $string1 . '|' . $string2 . '|' . $string3 . '|' );
}
echo $criteria;
```

$criteria will echo string1 and string2.  But string3 is blank.  When I echo from within the foreach loop $string 3 shows the value.

I really appreciate everyone's help!!  I think this is probably simmple but I have beaten my head.

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple `$comments` such that `$string1 == $comment` ?

Comment: This is what is returned when $criteria is echoed:

Comment: Communication |1|| Customer Service |2|| Dependability |3|| Initiative |4|| Job Knowledge |5|| Punctuality |1||

Comment: Please post `var_dump($criterias)`, `var_dump($criteriaValue)`, and `var_dump($comments)`.

Comment: `$string3` just has the value of `$comm` from the last time `$string == $comment` in the nested loops. If that was an empty comment, you'll get an empty string in `$criteria`. If you post the original data we can explain why this is happening.

Comment: Let me explain more - The contents of all arrays are coming from a string from a database.  When returned it looks like this:  Communication | 1 | asdfd | Customer Service | 2 | asdfafd | Dependability | 3 | asdfdf | Initiative | 4 | asdfadsf | Job Knowledge | 5 | 444444 | Punctuality | 1 | dadfdfd |.  I then explode using the "|" as the delimeter and then split the array using array_chunk( $ratingsArray, 3, false ); Here is the var_dumps:

Comment: CRITERIAS:   array
  0 => string 'Communication ' (length=14)
  1 => string ' Customer Service ' (length=18)
  2 => string ' Dependability ' (length=15)
  3 => string ' Initiative ' (length=12)
  4 => string ' Job Knowledge ' (length=15)
  5 => string ' Punctuality ' (length=13)
  6 => string ' ' (length=1)

Comment: CRITERIAVALUE:array
  'Communication ' => 
    array
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
  ' Customer Service ' => 
    array
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
  ' Dependability ' => 
    array
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
  ' Initiative ' => 
    array
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
  ' Job Knowledge ' => 
    array
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
  ' Punctuality ' => 
    array
      0 => string '1' (length=1)

Comment: COMMENTS:array
  'Communication ' => string ' asdfd ' (length=7)
  ' Customer Service ' => string ' asdfafd ' (length=9)
  ' Dependability ' => string ' asdfdf ' (length=8)
  ' Initiative ' => string ' asdfadsf ' (length=10)
  ' Job Knowledge ' => string ' 444444 ' (length=8)
  ' Punctuality ' => string ' dadfdfd ' (length=9)
  0 => string '' (length=0)

Comment: @REF, that's unreadable as comments.  Please edit that information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mysql_real_escape_string` function over `$string3` at the end. Try to echo `$string3` without applying any filter function.

Comment: The issue was an empty value.  I filtered and everything is working.